# please help me in building a query for the below mentioned table in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a table name `conversion` and i have these below mentioned columns in it i want to multiply Length\width row elements l*w of 'dimension' values and display them in another new table

Please let me know if anything changes for the same logic in ms access

probably it is simple but i dont know exact query to solve the problem waiting for your solutions

```
ID  area    length/width    dimensions   **new column(L*W) here** 
1   1           l            3                    3*5=15 
2   1           w            5
3   2           l            4
4   2           w            8
5   3           l            6
6   3           w            10
7   4           l            12
8   4           w            13
9   4           W            10
```

waiting for your reply

Comment: What about the last 3 rows?? How should they be multiplied??

Comment: Please complete your result column `new column(L*W) here` for all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query the table twice: once for lengths and once for widths and then join by area and multiply the values:

```
select length.area, length.dimension * width.dimension 
from 
  (select area, dimension from conversion where lenwidth = 'l') length
inner join 
  (select area, dimension from conversion where lenwidth = 'w') width
    on length.area = width.area;
```

Two remarks:

1. I suppose that it is a typo that you have two width entries for area 4? Otherwise you would have to decide which value to take in above select statement.
2. It would not be a good idea to keep the old table and have a new table holding the results. What if you change a value? You would have to remember to change the result accordingly every time. So either ditch the old table or use a view instead of a new table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *,
dimensions*(lead(dimensions) over(order by id)) product
from table1;
```

Or if you want for the set of area then

```
select *,
case when length_width='l' and (lead(length_width) over(order by id))='w'
then dimensions*(lead(dimensions) over(order by id))
else 0
end as product
from table1;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bdc6f/1)